# PowerApps - Make First Screen Default Screen for Editing

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Is there a way to ensure the default screen always loads first whether the form is in New, Edit, or View mode in SharePoint?

I have two screens in a PowerApps customized form.  The first screen is a user screen, and the second one is an admin screen that can only be navigated to from the user screen if the user can see the button.  In order to make sure the admin screen loaded the fields, I had to change the 'Item' property on the second screen to SharePointIntegration.Selected.  Otherwise, the form would continuously say "getting your data" when users clicked to the admin screen.   Unfortunately, this means when users edit a list item, the admin screen is the default screen loaded.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting `onStart` property of app to navigate to desired screen using `Navigate()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this article to set the on View, OnNew, OnEdit property of the SharePointIntegration control:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/SharePoint-Forms-multiple-screens/td-p/300042

If it doesn't sovle the issue, please provide specific steps so that I could reproduce your issue.

Comment: thank you Julie!  This worked perfectly.  You're a lifesaver <3